# Android Kotlin - post request with volley getting Nullpointer

Tags: json, http, post, kotlin, android-volley

I'm trying to create a simple login function within my app. Therefore i am sending a json object to my server. For the http request, i am using volley. But

I've tried several different ways, but i am getting all the time same errors. Below is my last code, i have tried.

```
    val url = "http://www.myurl.com"

    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
    params["name"] = "Myname"
    params["passwort"] = "MyPassword"
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(params)

    val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, Response.Listener { response ->
            // Process the json
            try {
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
        }, Response.ErrorListener {
            if (it != null) {

            }
        }
    )
    request.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,0, 1f)

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request)
}
```

Thats the error message i am always getting. The JSON i am creating is not empty. I dont understand why this is not working

E/JSON LENGTH:  2

E/VOLLEY REQUEST: [ ] https://www.myurl.com 0xb2d15379 NORMAL null

E/Volley: [58887] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array